# A grid container with an arbitrary number of columns without wrapping

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I need to display an arbitrary number of `grid-template-columns`.

I've tried `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 100px)`, but this wraps whatever rows exceed the width of its parent.

Setting a large upper bound like: `grid-template-columns: repeat(999, 100px)`, works, but it seems like there should be a better way.

Here's an example of what I'm working with:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BJbvEG

```css
.grid-1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 100px);
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.grid-2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(999, 100px);
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  overflow: auto;
}

.column {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(12, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<h3>Auto-fill takes an arbitrary number, but wraps. </h3>
<div class="grid-1">
  <div class="column">
    <div>one</div>
    <div>two</div>
    <div>three</div>
    <div>four</div>
    <div>five</div>
    <div>six</div>
    <div>seven</div>
    <div>eight</div>
    <div>nine</div>
    <div>ten</div>
    <div>eleven</div>
    <div>twelve</div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div>one</div>
    <div>two</div>
    <div>three</div>
    <div>four</div>
    <div>five</div>
    <div>six</div>
    <div>seven</div>
    <div>eight</div>
    <div>nine</div>
    <div>ten</div>
    <div>eleven</div>
    <div>twelve</div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div>one</div>
    <div>two</div>
    <div>three</div>
    <div>four</div>
    <div>five</div>
    <div>six</div>
    <div>seven</div>
    <div>eight</div>
    <div>nine</div>
    <div>ten</div>
    <div>eleven</div>
    <div>twelve</div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div>one</div>
    <div>two</div>
    <div>three</div>
    <div>four</div>
    <div>five</div>
    <div>six</div>
    <div>seven</div>
    <div>eight</div>
    <div>nine</div>
    <div>ten</div>
    <div>eleven</div>
    <div>twelve</div>
  </div>
</div>


<h3>A large upper bound works, but I'm looking for a better way.</h3>
<div class="grid-2">
  <div class="column">
    <div>one</div>
    <div>two</div>
    <div>three</div>
    <div>four</div>
    <div>five</div>
    <div>six</div>
    <div>seven</div>
    <div>eight</div>
    <div>nine</div>
    <div>ten</div>
    <div>eleven</div>
    <div>twelve</div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div>one</div>
    <div>two</div>
    <div>three</div>
    <div>four</div>
    <div>five</div>
    <div>six</div>
    <div>seven</div>
    <div>eight</div>
    <div>nine</div>
    <div>ten</div>
    <div>eleven</div>
    <div>twelve</div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div>one</div>
    <div>two</div>
    <div>three</div>
    <div>four</div>
    <div>five</div>
    <div>six</div>
    <div>seven</div>
    <div>eight</div>
    <div>nine</div>
    <div>ten</div>
    <div>eleven</div>
    <div>twelve</div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div>one</div>
    <div>two</div>
    <div>three</div>
    <div>four</div>
    <div>five</div>
    <div>six</div>
    <div>seven</div>
    <div>eight</div>
    <div>nine</div>
    <div>ten</div>
    <div>eleven</div>
    <div>twelve</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The pen I linked to should help explain. The bottom example is exactly what I want to achieve, but I think there should be a better way to do it.

Comment: you want the columns to overflow the grid container?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I'll have an `overflow: scroll` if that makes sense.

The problem is that I don't know the number of columns since it's user generated in the application. `auto-fill` will work with an arbitrary number, but wraps the content which isn't what I want.

Comment: well, why use CSS grid for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use [**`grid-template-columns`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns). That defines the column tracks in an [*explicit grid*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout#The_implicit_and_explicit_grid), which is a grid that you explicitly define.

Instead, use [**`grid-auto-columns`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-columns). That defines the column tracks in an [*implicit grid*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout#The_implicit_and_explicit_grid), which are the columns/rows that are automatically created outside of the explicit grid.

In other words, with `grid-auto-columns` you don't need to define any number of columns. Just let the grid container create them as needed.

Then, to keep all columns flowing horizontally, set them all to `grid-row: 1`.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.column {
  grid-row: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="column">
    <div>one</div>
    <div>two</div>
    <div>three</div>
    <div>four</div>
    <div>five</div>
    <div>six</div>
    <div>seven</div>
    <div>eight</div>
    <div>nine</div>
    <div>ten</div>
    <div>eleven</div>
    <div>twelve</div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div>one</div>
    <div>two</div>
    <div>three</div>
    <div>four</div>
    <div>five</div>
    <div>six</div>
    <div>seven</div>
    <div>eight</div>
    <div>nine</div>
    <div>ten</div>
    <div>eleven</div>
    <div>twelve</div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div>one</div>
    <div>two</div>
    <div>three</div>
    <div>four</div>
    <div>five</div>
    <div>six</div>
    <div>seven</div>
    <div>eight</div>
    <div>nine</div>
    <div>ten</div>
    <div>eleven</div>
    <div>twelve</div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div>one</div>
    <div>two</div>
    <div>three</div>
    <div>four</div>
    <div>five</div>
    <div>six</div>
    <div>seven</div>
    <div>eight</div>
    <div>nine</div>
    <div>ten</div>
    <div>eleven</div>
    <div>twelve</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

By the way, just adding `grid-row: 1` to the columns in your first example:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 100px)
```

... also works. But it's a bit of hack. With `grid-auto-columns` you have a more natural solution.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 100px);
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  overflow: auto;
}

.column {
  grid-row: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="column">
      <div>one</div>
      <div>two</div>
      <div>three</div>
      <div>four</div>
      <div>five</div>
      <div>six</div>
      <div>seven</div>
      <div>eight</div>
      <div>nine</div>
      <div>ten</div>
      <div>eleven</div>
      <div>twelve</div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div>one</div>
      <div>two</div>
      <div>three</div>
      <div>four</div>
      <div>five</div>
      <div>six</div>
      <div>seven</div>
      <div>eight</div>
      <div>nine</div>
      <div>ten</div>
      <div>eleven</div>
      <div>twelve</div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div>one</div>
      <div>two</div>
      <div>three</div>
      <div>four</div>
      <div>five</div>
      <div>six</div>
      <div>seven</div>
      <div>eight</div>
      <div>nine</div>
      <div>ten</div>
      <div>eleven</div>
      <div>twelve</div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div>one</div>
      <div>two</div>
      <div>three</div>
      <div>four</div>
      <div>five</div>
      <div>six</div>
      <div>seven</div>
      <div>eight</div>
      <div>nine</div>
      <div>ten</div>
      <div>eleven</div>
      <div>twelve</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with flexbox, just set the flex-items as no-growing, no-shrinking, fixed width elements

```css
.grid-1 {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  overflow:auto;
}
.column {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-1">
    <div class="column">
      <div>one</div> <div>two</div>  <div>three</div>  <div>four</div>
      <div>five</div><div>six</div><div>seven</div> <div>eight</div>     <div>nine</div> <div>ten</div> <div>eleven</div> <div>twelve</div>
    </div>
  <div class="column">
      <div>one</div> <div>two</div>  <div>three</div>  <div>four</div>
      <div>five</div><div>six</div><div>seven</div> <div>eight</div>     <div>nine</div> <div>ten</div> <div>eleven</div> <div>twelve</div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div>one</div> <div>two</div>  <div>three</div>  <div>four</div>
      <div>five</div><div>six</div><div>seven</div> <div>eight</div>     <div>nine</div> <div>ten</div> <div>eleven</div> <div>twelve</div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div>one</div> <div>two</div>  <div>three</div>  <div>four</div>
      <div>five</div><div>six</div><div>seven</div> <div>eight</div>     <div>nine</div> <div>ten</div> <div>eleven</div> <div>twelve</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works well, but @Michael_B answered my question as it pertains to css grid.

Comment: @Dan guess that's a better solution then :) Flexbox has slightly better support than grid though, so you might even want to use this as a fallback for the other method, for IE and the lesser browsers. CSS grid is awesome at overriding  the fallbacks, so it will be a quite easy https://rachelandrew.co.uk/css/cheatsheets/grid-fallbacks